# Can inheriting unwanted class members affect application's performance?

Tags: javascript, class, oop, inheritance

Let's say we have some super class X:

```
class X {
   // Method needed in most of the instances.
   public a() { }

   // Method needed in minority of instances.
   public b() { // Large method body implementation. }
}
```

And we have some class `Y extends X` where `Y` is being instantiated significant amount of times.

My question is whether presence of method `b` in all instances, despite being needed in few, considering it's large content, can negatively affect project's speed or size. Is this the situation where the method `b` perhaps shouldn't be member of class `X` since it is highly underutilized?

To be clear this situation occurred in JavaScript code.

Comment: Which programming language is this question based on? I would assume that this is not common for all

Comment: It was supposed to be just pseudo code, but to be specific this problem occurred in my JavaScript code. I would also be interested to know whether Java performance could be impacted negatively by such code.

Comment: It's not like the methods are copied to each instance, in most languages they're shared via the class object somehow (in Javascript, that's via the `prototype`). So it doesn't really impact much at all. The better question might be why a class inherits another class when large parts of the parent class are apparently irrelevant to the child class…?

Comment: It is really just abstract example, it is not the case that superclass in underutilized as a whole, just single given member. The reason for inheritance should not be put into question, perhaps just structure of the superclass. Anyway sharing single implementation via prototype seems like answer to my question if it's correct.

Comment: Why not write a simple benchmark to see what happens? This is way to broad to be answered in a general way

Comment: I thought class instantiation/inheritance follows common patterns across modern languages, I wasn't sure if the question is too broad. Now I know, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, absolutely not. First, the method is not present in all the individual instances but only in the class' `.prototype` object. Second, the size of methods (the function objects) is not related to the code size of their body.